# Push value of arrivalDate in array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object

I would like to store every arrivalDate in my array list.
Someone could tell me how can I do it?
But my array is still empty.

JSON returned by the API:

```
{
    "reservations": {
        "reservationInfo": [
             {
                 "roomStay": {
                      "arrivalDate": "11am"
                 },
                 "WeatherR": {
                      "sound": "cloudy"
                 },
             },
             {
                  "roomStay": {
                      "arrivalDate": "7pm"
                   },
                  "WeatherR": {
                       "sound": "cloudy"
                   },
             }
        ]
    }
}
```

component.ts

```
searchForReservation() {
  alert('hello');
  this.http.get('/api/searchForReservation')
    .subscribe((data) => {
      this.ddataIno = data;
      this.ddataIno = this.ddataIno.result.reservations.reservationInfo;
      console.log('number of value', this.ddataIno.length);
      console.log('content', this.ddataIno);
      for (let i = 0; i <= this.ddataIno[i].length; i++) {
        this.list = this.ddataIno.roomStay.arrivalDate;
      }
      console.log('store array', this.list)

    })
}
```

Comment: Is `this.ddataIno[i].roomStay.arrivalDate`. But you should check [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) methods of an array. in your case `this.list=data.reservations.reservationInfo.map(x=>x.roomStay.arrivalDate)` give you an array of string with the data. NOTE: I feel that you're not using the httpClient else the old http. (generally you has not need use "result" simply "data"

Answer (score 0):

```
searchForReservation() {
  alert('hello');
  this.http.get('/api/searchForReservation')
    .subscribe((data) => {
      const reservationInfo = this.data.result.reservations.reservationInfo;
      this.list = reservationInfo.map(e => e.roomStay.arrivalDate);
    })
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but what is 'e'?

Comment: the `map` function iterates the array. `e` is the current element

Comment: Ok thank you.. but unfortunately I have an error.. Got it.. But I have an error, sorry.. Parameter 'i' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)
Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example in vanilla JS. You would need to make some small adjustments for angular, like `this.list = ...` instead of `let list = ...`

Using Array#map, you can create a new array from the JSON object

```
data.reservations.reservationInfo.map(r => r.roomStay.arrivalDate)
```

```js
let data = {
  "reservations": {
    "reservationInfo": [{
        "roomStay": {
          "arrivalDate": "11am"
        },
        "WeatherR": {
          "sound": "cloudy"
        },
      },
      {
        "roomStay": {
          "arrivalDate": "7pm"
        },
        "WeatherR": {
          "sound": "cloudy"
        },
      }
    ]
  }
}

// declare your list as an array at the top
// list: []

// below would start off as 'this.list'
let list = data.reservations.reservationInfo.map(r => r.roomStay.arrivalDate);

console.log(list);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just to clarify, the JSON I provided come from my browser. I don't have any JSON file in my project. It doesn't matter? Thank you

Comment: No, you can plug this in directly to your code at the place where you receive the json.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is just reassigning the value of `this.list`

I suggest reading up on [Array methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

I would use a map method, e.g.

```
this.list = this.ddataIno.result.reservations.reservationInfo.map(i => i.roomStay.arrivaldate);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but what is 'i'? ..

Comment: variable that represents an item in the `reservationInfo` array

Comment: Got it.. But I have an error, sorry.. Parameter 'i' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)

Comment: So add a type to `i`. `.map((i: any) => i.roomStay.arrivalDate);`. That's a different error and a different question though. Swap `any` with a type you've declared for an item in `reservationInfo` if you have one.